map the same entity to different tables dynamically
I was working on a project recently where I hit a peculiar problem. The problem was I wanted to map the same entity to different tables dynamically. In my case, I am using oracle.
I need to use JPA Repository and also using Derived Query Methods in Spring Data JPA Repositories

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
